# How to propagate lexical scope in a compiler, specifically around step-by-step functions?

Tags: compiler, scope

I am working on a compiler in TypeScript, and currently am focused on how to pass around the "lexical scope" to the relevant objects. Essentially every time there is a conceptual major branch in the code, there is a new lexical scope created and assigned to that AST node, pointing to its parent for parent variables.

```
module scope
  class scope 
    function scope
      function scope # say we have nested functions
        conditional-branch scope
          conditional-branch scope
            ...
```

But I'm wondering typically how you are supposed to handle variables that are defined in random places in a linear sequence.

```
let a = 10
// calling c before it's defined throws an error
console.log(c)
let b = 'foo'
console.log(a, b)
let c = true
// calling d throws an error here
console.log(d)
console.log(a, b, c)
let d = 3.14
```

Does this mean that every time a variable is introduced, we fork the scope as well? Then everything in the list/chain preceding gets the same scope, only until the next variable is introduced then we fork the scope again, etc.. Just wondering because that seems like a lot of scopes to keep around.

Anything else I'm missing? It gets tricky it seems when you have functions like in JavaScript which can appear after the current code.

```
let a = 10;
// calling c before it's defined throws an error
console.log(c);
let b = "foo";
console.log(a, b);
logit("hello")
let c = true;
// calling d throws an error here
console.log(d);
console.log(a, b, c);
let d = 3.14;

function logit(msg) {
  console.log(a, b, c, d, msg)
}
```

What happens in situations like these? How does it get wired up? Any other complex situations to consider?

It would seem for that last case, you would have to fork the step-wise scope at the point of calling `logit`, but also have a `logit` scope with its own local variables as well. So if you called `logit` two or three times with more and more of it's dependent variables initialized, it would somehow know that. I can't see how that would work.

Or perhaps it creates "shadow functions" for each step/usage of the nested function! Like it creates a new function which inherits the two scopes. So then it's really internally calling 2 or 3 separate functions for `logit`, like `gen_logit1`, `gen_logit2`, etc..

Comment: Many languages would simply say that logit was undefined. Others would move all the variable declarations to the top of the function, but not assign them values yet. Up to you.

Comment: How does it work though, implementation-wise, is what I'm wondering.

Comment: how does which one work?

Comment: @user253751: the OP did not ask about "many languages", he asked specificially about TypeScript.

Comment: @DocBrown the compiler is written in TypeScript

Comment: @Lance: a compiler for which language are you developing? Javascript? Typescript? Or something else, with different lexical scope rules?

Comment: When you say “throws an error”, please make clear exactly who does this. Is it the compiler not accepting a statement, or is it a compiled statement that runs and the wise an exception?

Answer (score 3):

> But I'm wondering typically how you are supposed to handle variables that are defined in random places in a linear sequence.
> Does this mean that every time a variable is introduced, we fork the scope as well?

It would be error-prone to automatically create a nested scope for each new variable declaration (in a linear sequence that doesn't obviously merit a new scope).  We probably want some form of hiding of outer scope variables within an inner scope, but not in all contexts, and certainly not automatically — errors (i.e. duplicate definition) in the same scope are important.

> How to propagate lexical scope in a compiler, specifically around step-by-step functions?

Firstly, this is typically accommodated dynamically during a pass over the language file input, and requires a few data structures.  For one, a dynamic scope structure, which supports:

- enter/push new scope, that is automatically

  - linked to current scope as its parent/encloser
  - made the new current scope
- leave/pop current scope

  - making the parent scope the new current scope
- enter identifier into scope

  - the given identifier is added to the current scope
- search scope for identifier

  - search from current scope, if not found, search parent after parent

Let's note that the scope table is not the same as a symbol table, which describes variables, but is not necessarily a dynamic structure as the scope structure.

Being dynamic, the scope structure is effectively destroyed during the pass over the input, in particular as each scope is popped, they disappear (may be lost or may be referred to by symbols), and by the time this pass over the input is done, the (the outer) scope structure could be empty (depending on the language and other choices).

However, during this pass over the input, the compiler should be constructing the symbol table, which will survive the input pass, and have collected all variables.

The scope data structure refers to symbols.  The purpose of the scope structure is to resolve identifiers in context (of a pass over the input) — while the symbol table instead collects symbols to be used after in code generation, and for example, is referred to by AST nodes.  The output of this pass (input for the next compiler phase) then is (a) the AST for statements and such, (b) a symbol table, and (c) possibly some scoping information (but not a single top-level scoping table).

The scope structure is a bit like a tree, but only one path from top-level to leaf is designated as "current" with regard to the dynamic pass over the language input.  The nodes of the scope structure may refer to parents, so in the end, there may be a bushy inverse tree like structure whose leaves are referred to by symbols.  (AST identifier node refers to symbol, which refers to scope, which refers to parent scope, and some reverse linkage as well in some form, so scope has symbols.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. If you are trying to compile your own language, then you get to decide.

Many languages (e.g. Lua) would simply say that `logit` was undefined at the point where it's called.

Others (e.g. Python, JavaScript) would move all the variable declarations in that scope to the top of scope, but not assign them values until the point where their declaration actually appears. Python does this with assignments, despite not even having declarations. In JavaScript, a variable with no assigned value has the value `undefined`. In Python, accessing it throws an exception.

Answer (score -3):

You have nested scopes. If you compile C you have a scope for global variables, static variables, functions with parameters first, then nested variable scopes.

You create new scopes, add identifiers to them, delete scopes, based on the order of your code. When you call console.log(c) c hasnt been added to any scope yet. If you compile let a=1 you would add a to the current scope unless it is already in that scope when you get an error.